Implementing retries in StepExecutionListener in spring batch
As far as I understand the interaction between Tasklet and StepExecutionListener happens this way:

Before Step: The StepExecutionListener's beforeStep() method is called. This
provides an opportunity to perform any necessary initialization or
setup tasks before the Step starts.
Tasklet Execution: The Tasklet's execute() method is called repeatedly, processing
chunks of items. The Tasklet performs the core processing logic for
each chunk. The StepContribution and ChunkContext are passed to the
Tasklet, providing information about the current chunk and the
Step's execution.
After Step: The StepExecutionListener's afterStep() method is called. This
provides an opportunity to perform any cleanup or finalization tasks
after the Step completes.

Consider the case where execute() fails. For this I want to implement 5 retries of the step until the step is successful in the listener.
I am very new to spring. Here are the questions I wish to get clarity on:

How does this work internally? Who calls StepExecutionListener's beforeStep() then Tasklet's execute() then StepExecutionListener's afterStep(). How do they share information between them? (If there is a good documentation for this please do share it)
Is there any better way to do this?




How does this work internally? Who calls StepExecutionListener's beforeStep() then Tasklet's execute() then StepExecutionListener's afterStep(). How do they share information between them? (If there is a good documentation for this please do share it)


It is the AbstractStep class that drives the execution of all Step implementations provided by Spring Batch (TaskletStep is one of them when using a tasklet).


Is there any better way to do this?


I think so. The step execution lister is not the best place to implement retries (it is either too early or too late to put the retry logic in the listener). For chunk-oriented tasklets, Spring Batch provides the retry feature already (just specify the retry policy when building the chunk-oriented tasklet).
For simple tasklets (ie not item oriented), there is no built-in retry feature. What you can do is use a RetryTemplate inside the tasklet#execute and handle any failure by throwing an exception after 5 retries.

Thanks for answering. I am able to understand the internal calls. But which class calls AbstractStep#execute to start the whole step execution?.

It is the StepHandler which calls step#execute, which is in turn called at the upper level by AbstractJob#execute.
